# I can't get useDelimiter() to cooperate

Tags: java

I am working on a Java project and I am trying to get useDelimiter to remove everything except the text in between "=" and ",". For example, on the first line of the file I would like to keep "ThermostatNight".

This is what the text file looks like:

```
   Event=ThermostatNight,time=0

   Event=LightOn,time=2000
```

I've been able to do the exact opposite using this code:

```
s.useDelimiter("=(.*?),");
```

Is there any way I can tweak this to do the opposite?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
s.replaceAll("([a-zA-Z]*=)([a-zA-Z]*)(,.*)","$2")
```

This is following the pattern you show. If it changes you will have to change this regex.

See it here: http://regex101.com/r/jN8iR8

See the section Match groups, you will see that group 2 is your desired result.

The replace all method is replacing everything just for the group 2 which is what is in between `=` and `,`

**Edit**

As the OP said that s is a `Scanner`

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("YOURFILE"));
while (s.hasNext()) {
    String text = s.next();
    System.out.println( text.replaceAll("([a-zA-Z]*=)([a-zA-Z]*)(,.*)","$2") );
}
s.close();
```

Comment: Nope, still not getting "ThermostatNight" back

Comment: I just tested here and it is working. Note that it isnt useDelimiter. It is replaceAll method.

Comment: I am getting an error "The method replaceAll(String, String) is undefined for the type Scanner". I should note that I am new to Java.

Comment: See my last edit. Change YOURFILE for the path that your are reading the file.